# Light intensity effect on plant transpiration

Tags: plant-physiology, photosynthesis, cellular-respiration

In the graph of light intensity versus rate of transpiration, the rate increases up to a certain point but then remains constant. What is the reason that it stays constant, is there a limiting factor such as water?

Comment: Can you add the graph you refer to to your post and add more backgrounds and a link to the source of your information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of stomata on the leaf is the limiting factor. Light causes the stomata to open, more so with increasing light intensity. Once all the stomata are fully open, the transpiration rate rate cannot increase any further (for a given set of temperature and relative humidity conditions).